# After resize stroke width changes absurdly in raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael, transform, scale

I have two similar svg objects. I scale one of them by 3 and do some stuff. And after that, I resize it to its original size (scale by 1). However, the strange thing is its stroke width changes, gets smaller.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Is there a simple workaround/hack? I'm drawing zillions of shapes.
Any help would be appreciated.

The full code is

```
pageWidth = $(window).width();
pageHeight = $(window).height();
r = Raphael("holder",pageWidth, pageHeight);

r.setStart();
circ = r.circle(250,250,100,100).attr({'stroke-width':10, 'fill':'green'});
rct = r.rect(200,200,100,100).attr({'stroke-width':2,'fill':'grey'});

st = r.setFinish();

circ2 = r.circle(350,450,100,100).attr({'stroke-width':10, 'fill':'green'});
rct2 = r.rect(300,400,100,100).attr({'stroke-width':2,'fill':'grey'});


x = circ.attr('cx');
y = circ.attr('cy');

setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s3,3,'+x+','+y},1500)},1000);

setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s1,1'},1500)},3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WFtaG/23/

Comment: Have a look at this, it could be related - http://ehouais.net/posts/243

Comment: @Neil That link no longer works, it seems to have moved here: http://ehouais.net/2012/04/real-vector-graphics-know-how-to-scale/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s3,3,'+x+','+y},1500)},1000);
setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s1,1,'+x+','+y},1500)},3000);
```

​

As far as I know it's about antialiasing. You could try this:

```
//setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s3,3,'+x+','+y},1500)},1000);
//setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'s1,1'},1500)},3000);
setTimeout(function(){st.animate({'transform':'t1,1'},15000)},3000);
```

Comment: Sorry I was too busy yesterday. I'll try and let you know if it works.

Comment: Appending center coordinates to s1,1 works. Yet, I couldn't understand your second snippet as it does nothing new.

Comment: Ignore it. I was wrong about aa. The fact is that if you scale the object by factor 3, stroke width is scaled by 1/3?! After scaling to original size, the stroke width remain the same. Could be bug in library. I shortly read the scale params parsing. Find else if (command == "s") in lib. This part seems ok. Part if (absolute) is called for "S" command instead of "s". The possible bug could be after case "stroke-width":

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

Specifically, using an animation to increase the size of a circle while the mouse is over it, the stroke width became ~1/2 of what it should be during the animation, and during subsequent animations it would regain its proper size during the "growing" animation but become half-width again when that animation ended, and stay half-size during and after the "shrinking" animation.  The change in width was not animated -- the line would "pop" to the thin width at the final end of the growing (with bounce) animation, for example.  This is somewhat different from the misbehavior of the jsfiddle example in the original question above, but the following fix fixes both.

Inspired by Phillippe Deschaseaux's [article](http://ehouais.net/2012/04/real-vector-graphics-know-how-to-scale/) (pointed out by Neil's comment above) and Phillippe's [fix](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/566/files) for a similar problem, I found that a similar fix fixed this problem.

Specifically, comment out the following 6 lines in raphael.js:

```
                case "stroke-width":
                    //if (o._.sx != 1 || o._.sy != 1) {
                    //    value /= mmax(abs(o._.sx), abs(o._.sy)) || 1;
                    //}
                    //if (o.paper._vbSize) {
                    //    value *= o.paper._vbSize;
                    //}
                    node.setAttribute(att, value);
```

(Yes, this is where DraganS's comment (to his accepted answer) suggested the problem might be.)

Phillippe's fix for his problem was to eliminate the last three commented lines, which adjust the stroke width when the container is resized (what Phillippe was doing), while the fix for my problem is to eliminate the first three lines, which adjust the stroke width based on the scale of the object (what I was doing).  Of course, eliminating all 6 lines fixes both of these problems.

I suspect this is a platform-dependent problem.  (I am using Safari.)  In this case, the correct fix to raphael.js would be more complicated than just removing those six lines, perhaps explaining why it hasn't been fixed yet (and why those six lines were ever written in the first place).

In other words, if your code needs to run correctly on all kinds of browsers, you should do some checking to see which browsers/versions need those six lines there and which ones need them gone.  If you do this, be sure to send Dmitry Baranovskiy a note!

Comment: Although the issue is not new, thanks for this notable answer. At that time I used the workaround (i.e. appending `s1,1`) and finished the project. I hope it will help someone else.